# ¿Actualizar datos de la base de datos laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy intentando actualizar un registro de la forma en la que se muestra en la documentación de laravel y también de algunos sitios web y vídeos que miré, pero no pude, no me sale ningun error pero tampoco se actualizan los campos.

Entonces pensé que de la manera como agregro un usuario a la base de datos,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $usuarios = new Usuario();

    $usuarios->nombre = $request->Nombre;
    $usuarios->apellidos = $request->Apellidos;
    $usuarios->sexo = $request->Sexo;
    $usuarios->edad = $request->Edad;
    $usuarios->correo = $request->Correo;

    $usuarios->save();
    
    return redirect('usuarios'); 
}
```

también podría actualizarlo solo cambiando la primera línea de la función update

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $usuario = Usuario::findOrFail($id);
    return view('usuarios.edit' , compact('usuario'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request,  $id)
{

   $usuario = Usuario::findOrFail($id);
    
    $usuario->nombre = $request->Nombre;
    $usuario->apellidos = $request->Apellidos;
    $usuario->sexo = $request->Sexo;
    $usuario->edad = $request->Edad;
    $usuario->correo = $request->Correo;

    

    $usuario->save();
    
    return redirect('usuarios'); 
}
```

cabe resaltar que de esa manera me actualiza los datos perfectamente , pero mi pregunta es: ¿está mal actualizarlo de esa manera? o si no es una mala práctica hacerlo de esa manera.

Comment: se supone que si haces `= new User()` estas creando un nuevo registro, pero por el contrario si deseas actualzar entonces no creas una nueva instancia de tu clase `User` sino que como muestras casi al final debes hacer `$user = User::findOrFail();` para de este modo actualizar siempre y cuando encuentre coincidencia por ejemplo por medio del `$id` y en caso contrario mostrar una excepción

Comment: @element solo mostré los 2 para que vieran como creaba y como actualizaba eso lo tengo claro , mi pregunta es si es una buena marera actualizar los registro de esa forma , lo pregunto porque en pagina u vídeo donde allá buscado tienen otra forma de actualizar.

Comment: Solo una sugerencia extra @NeiiderMartinezRivas, para futuras preguntas es mejor copiar y pegar el código que colocar imágenes, ya que éstas se podría romper su enlace a futuro. (si gustas te invito a editar la pregunta y cambiar las imágenes por texto, los mismos fragmentos de código ya que aceptaste una respuesta)

Comment: @CesarRomero Gracias por la sugerencia , tienes toda la razón , por lo cual seguí tu consejo y cambie la imágenes por código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es correcto actualizarlo de esa manera, aunque hay otros métodos que pueden ahorrar líneas de código y hacer más «profesional» el código, dentro de los estándares de Laravel:

1. **Route Model Binding**

   Consiste en «traer» el modelo directamente desde la ruta, asumiendo que estemos pasando su llave primaria como parámetro:

   ```
   Route::put('actualizar-usuario/{usuario}', 'UsuarioController@update');
   ```

   Y en el controlador recibes directamente el modelo que vas a actualizar:

   ```
   public function update(Usuario $usuario, Request $request)
   {
       // trabajar con los campos del request
       $usuario->save();
   }
   ```

   Puedes ver más información en: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding
2. **Utilizar el método fill**

   En caso que no necesites manipular los datos que recibes del request (según lo que veo en el código, es tu caso), no necesitas asignar los valores del request línea a línea a las propiedades del objeto, tan solo pasas el array del request al método fill y este se encarga de actualizar los campos permitidos:

   ```
   public function update(Usuario $usuario, Request $request)
   {
       $usuario->fill($request->all());
       $usuario->save();
   }
   ```

   El método fill acepta un array como parámetro.

   Puedes ver más información en: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: esas 2 formas ya las intente y ninguna me funciona cuando le doy a actualizar hace todo menos actualizar el campo tampoco me sale ningún en error , solo me refirije a la vista que le indico y ya , y la verdad no se porque

Comment: Probablemente tienes algo mal en la definición del modelo.

Comment: mira mi modelo 

`<?php`

`namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre' , 'apellidos' , 'edad' , 'sexo' , 'correo'];
}
`

Comment: En tu método Update `update(Request $request,  $id)` lo cambiaste por `update(Usuario $usuario, Request $request)`?

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas he adaptado los nombres de variables y clases a tu convención.

Comment: @CesarRomero no , no lo he cambiado , lo tengo asi : `public function update(Request $request,  $id)
{`

Comment: Por eso quizás no te funcione si vas a probar con los métodos que coloco @Shaz debes cambiar tu método Update a `update(Usuario $usuario, Request $request)`

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a la documentación de Laravel se puede partir de lo siguiente

**Actualizar un solo registro**

```
$app = ModelName::find($id);
$app->name = $request->name;
$app->email = $request->email;
$save();
```

**Actualizar con base en una condición**

```
$app = App\ModelName::find(1);
$app->where("status", 1)
    ->update(["keyOne" => $valueOne, "keyTwo" => $valueTwo]);
```

Como observas cuando haces una actualización masiva puedes establecer una o mas condiciones, entonces lo valores a actualizar se reciben en forma de array asociativo

Entonces si lo comparas con la respuesta de @Shaz no solo observarás mas de una opción, si no que puedes hacer uso de opciones que acorten muchísimo el código(como el mismo lo muestra)

(Referencia)[https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models]